# How to prove that a certain expression is $\sigma$-finite?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be the measure on $\mathbb{R}$ , where $\mu(A)$ = the number of rationals in the
set $A$ ($\mu(A)=\infty$ if there are infnitely many rationals). Assume $\mu$ is a measure, I want to show that $\mu$ is $\sigma$ -finite.

My answer is different from the official solution, may I ask is it correct? Here's my answer:

For all $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, $\{x\}$ is in $\mathbb{R}$ and thus in the $\sigma$ -algebra, so their countable union $\mathbb{Q}$ is also in the sigma algebra, so $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ is in the $\sigma$-algebra, so $\mathbb{R}$ is the countable union $(\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q})\cup \left ( \cup _n \{x_n\} \right )$, where $x_n$ is the n-th rational number. Here $\mu(\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q})=0$ and $\mu(\{x_n\})=1$.

Comment: Yes it’s correct, though the first part of the first sentence is written awkwardly and not needed

Comment: This is okay if the $\sigma$-algebra that is involved contains for every $x\in\mathbb Q$ the set $\{x\}$ and usually that is the case. But if we deal e.g. with measure space $(\mathbb R,\mathcal A,\mu)$ where $\mathcal A=\{\varnothing, \mathbb R\}$ and $\mu(\mathbb R)=\infty$ then $\mu$ is not $\sigma$-finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were grading this on an exam, I'd be reluctant to give it a perfect score due to some clarity issues

> For all $ x \in \mathbb{Q} $, $\{ x \} $ is in $ \mathbb{R} $.

This is a nitpick, but $ \{ x \} \in \mathscr{P}\mathbb{R} $, not $ \mathbb{R} $.  But perhaps you're using "in" loosely to mean "subset of" so let's let it slide.  But (and I would never punish a student for being pedantic, this is just style advice) the observation that subsets of $ \mathbb{Q} $ are also subsets of $ \mathbb{R} $ is not worthy of mention.

> ... and thus in the $ \sigma $-algebra...

What $ \sigma $-algebra?  This is the first time someone is mentioning a $ \sigma $-algebra.  Do you mean the $ \sigma $-algebra of $ \mu $-measurable sets?  If so, then say so, and also you ought to justify that if it matters.  Or don't mention it if it doesn't matter.

It is also good form, though not strictly required, to state the definition of the property ($ \sigma $-finiteness) that you are trying to prove.  In the context of mathematical dialogue (as you're doing here on MSE), such statements of definitions can dispel ambiguities like "are the sets in the union required to be measurable?".

But other than these relative nitpicks, the ending seems to make it clear that you have the right idea.

Comment: “are the sets in the union required to be measurable” This is not ambiguous at all. The answer is obviously yes.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I will definitely correct my mistakes.